# Explicitly forcing Class reference to namespace does not work

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a ASP .NET 5 Project with an ApplicationUser model. I have now decided to move out all Database related models to an external Project (called BusinessLogic) to have more structure in my solution.

I just forgot to delete the ApplicationUser class in the Models directory, thats why i have both of these classes in different folders. While creating a ViewModel for a Dashboard, i "stumbled" upon this:

```
using ApplicationUser = MyProject.BusinessLogic.Models.ApplicationUser;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject.Application.Models
{
    public class AdminViewModel
    {
        public List<MyProject.BusinessLogic.Models.ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why do i still need to explicitly write the path to ApplicationUser when i already defined it as "using ApplicationUser = ...."?

Comment: you can, but you don't need. Are you getting any errors if you just use ApplicationUser?

Comment: Well, since i use ApplicationUser in combination with an ApplicationDbContext class (sets all tables and models for the database) it will throw an error since it is the wrong class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to close this question since it is more of a c# understanding thing and you normally shouldn't have models/classes named the same.

Those references are named "using alias directive" for anybody wondering.

Here is a link for the interested ones: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but could you try with the statement:

```
using ApplicationUsr = MyProject.BusinessLogic.Models.ApplicationUser;
```

Then use ApplicationUsr.